# Accessing firestore from self-hosted server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to be able to access (read, write) firestore from my self-hosted server (not on gcloud).

I also need to reserve write permissions to the app hosted on my self-hosted server, and allow noone else to be able to write to the server, so the security rules for write applications are denied by default.

According to this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries

using a service account should allow me to be able to access all firebase products, including firestore, without any restrictions.

But, as soon as I restrict the security rules, I am unable to write to firestore from my service, instantiated with service account credentials following the steps in this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

I get the following error:
`PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

What do I have to do to allow my application to write to firestore from my own servers?

Update:
I am using java for my backend applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was facing has already been reported here:

https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore/issues/431

The fix was an odd one, and cannot be explained without going deep into the SDK and how it works, which I did not have time to check:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Servers (or cloud functions) are secure environment which can be accessed only by you and people you have authorized. You don't actually use the [Firebase Client SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries) in a server. Instead you use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). It uses a [service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) and has privileged access to your Firebase Project.

**What does privileged access mean?**

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) has explained it all but long story short it has complete access like you to the project. It does not follow any security rules.

If you are implementing the Admin SDK which will deal with API requests coming from your clients then make sure you authenticate them. To do so you would ideally pass the Firebase ID Token from your frontend to the API and [verify](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)
it using the Admin SDK which returns a [decoded token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) object containing UID, custom claims and some metadata about that user.

I'm not sure which language you use but here's a simple getting started for NodeJS:

```
// Install the Admin SDK
npm install firebase-admin
```

```
// index.js

const admin = require("firebase-admin")

const path = require("path");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("path/to/key")),
  databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com/"
})

const firestore = admin.firestore()
const auth = admin.auth()

// firebase.firestore() and firebase.auth() in client SDKs
```

Rest of the syntax is mostly the same as Client SDK.

You can create a service account from the project settings.

[image]